# Executing a saved Microsoft Access query with pyodbc

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc

I am trying to write a Python script to execute a saved query in Microsoft Access using pyodbc.  I connect to the database and retreive the cursor.  If I run:

```
>>> database_cursor = get_cursor("path_to_database.accdb") #This is a function I wrote that returns the cursor
>>> database_cursor.tables()
```

I can see the saved query is in there and is of type VIEW.  Jamming it into a namedtuple, it looks like this:

```
table(catalog='.\\path_to_database.ACCDB', schema=None, name='QueryIWantToExecute', type='VIEW', remarks=None)
```

If I open my saved query in Microsoft Access and copy-paste the SQL from the SQL view for this query and run the .execute() function, it does indeed return the results of my query.

```
>>> database_cursor.execute("SQL copy-pasted from Access here")
#This works and returns the results I want
```

Is it possible to access the SQL from my Python script somehow?  Running the .statistics() method on my returned table yields the following error:

```
>>> database_cursor.statistics('QueryIWantToExecute')
...some output ommitted...
pypyodbc.Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Query support unavailable.')
```

The .columns() function does return some columns from this table, but I don't see how this gets me to running the query from my script.

```
>>> database_cursor.columns('QueryIWantToExecute')
[('.\\path_to_database.accdb', None, 'QueryIWantToExecute', 'cause', -9, 'VARCHAR', 20, 40, None, None, 1, None, None, -9, None, 40, 1, 'YES', 1),
 ('.\\path_to_database.accdb', None, 'QueryIWantToExecute', 'CountOfThings', 4, 'INTEGER', 10, 4, 0, 10, 1, None, None, 4, None, None, 2, 'YES', 2)]
```

Consulting the pyodbc cursor documentation here (https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor), I am only seeing ways to execute queries once you already have the SQL.  How can I pull the SQL from Access?

Comment: Have you tried `database_cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM QueryIWantToExecute")` ?

Comment: That worked, and now I feel like I should have been able to figure that out...  If you format your comment like an answer, I will accept it.  Thanks!